# Can I get a data from a specific node only in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

My Cassandra set 1 Datacenter, 2 Nodes and Replication Factor is 2.

I had some issue with 1 node was down. I'll repair it by QUORUM read repair instead of nodetool one.
After repair, I have to check nodes have same data each other.

As I know, I can't choose specific node with Consistency Level One when I read data. (Maybe cause of Dynamic Snitch). I wanna know the way without node down.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to query a specific node provided you know that it is a replica of the partition by setting the consistency level to either `ONE` or `LOCAL_ONE`.

For example, connect to the node locally with cqlsh then set:

```
cqlsh> CONSISTENCY ONE;
```

Note that this is technically unnecessary since the default consistency for cqlsh is already `ONE`. If the node is a replica then cqlsh will only query that node.

Obviously in your case we already know that all nodes in the DC are replicas since there are only 2 nodes with a replication factor of 2. Cheers!